# Verbose logging for UserAgentApplication

Tags: azure, azure-ad-msal

Attempting to turn on verbose message that is outlined in this document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-logging

but getting
Unhandled rejection TypeError: _this.logger.warning is not a function

I attempted to minimize the number of options for the configuration for logger to only two the level and logger callback, but does not seem to work

```
function loggerCallback(logLevel, message, containsPii) {
    console.log(message);
    }
}
 var msalConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '{client id}', //This is your client ID
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant id}" //This is your tenant info
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true
    },
    system: {
        logger: {
            localCallback: loggerCallback,
            level: Msal.LogLevel.Verbose,
            piiLoggingEnabled: false,
            correlationId: '1234'
        }
    }
};

var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
```

// initialization code for requestOjbect, graphConfig

```
function signIn() {
    myMSALObj.loginPopup(requestObj).then(function (loginResponse) {
        //Successful login
        showWelcomeMessage();
        //Call MS Graph using the token in the response
        acquireTokenPopupAndCallMSGraph();
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //Please check the console for errors
        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

When the code call to authenticate the user via popup, an empty pop up shows with the error message in the browser console, the expectation would be to have the popup show the user names for azure ad login.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. This is a bug currently. You can refer to [this github issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/32070) for any updates.

You can also try with the workground [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/728#event-2366177209) though it doesn't work for me. This issue owner said that he can remove this error by adding all logger fields.

Comment: If the answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.